# Formatting Time in Python by Concatenating Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame with 3 columns: "Hour", "Minute", & "Second" that I need to concatenate into time.

I am hoping to use a date later in my analysis but but for the time being I'm creating a temp column called time. My problem is that the hour, minutes & seconds have either 1 or 2 digits, when there are 2, I want to use the number but if there's 1 [1-9], then I want to write "01" or "02" or ... or "09". Heres's my code

```
dfdate['AgentDateTime'] = 
(dfdate['DISPATCH_HOUR'] if (len(dfdate['DISPATCH_HOUR'])==2) else ("0"+dfdate['DISPATCH_HOUR'])) 
+ ":" 
+ (dfdate['DISPATCH_MIN'] if (len(dfdate['DISPATCH_MIN'])==2) else ("0"+dfdate['DISPATCH_MIN'])) 
+ ":" 
+ (dfdate['DISPATCH_SEC'] if (len(dfdate['DISPATCH_SEC'])==2) else ("0"+dfdate['DISPATCH_SEC']))
```

For whatever reason, 10 is being returned, 010, and 11 as 011 and so on. How do I fix this, because when I query an individual line with a double digit number,

```
len(dfdate['DISPATCH_MIN'])==2
```

returns True meaning the if statement's above should return the row without the 0 prefixed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for that. Just slice out your columns, join them with agg, and then pass the result to `pd.to_timedelta`.

```
v = dfdate[['DISPATCH_HOUR', 'DISPATCH_MIN', 'DISPATCH_SEC']]
dfdate['AgentDateTime'] = pd.to_timedelta(
    v.astype(str).agg(':'.join, axis=1), errors='coerce')
```